# Can't read cookie set by javascript in php

Tags: javascript, php, cookies

This is my code for my setting of cookie in javascript and reading of cookie in php.

jsglobalset.html:

```
<script>
var values = "poppy"
document.cookie = "textout=" + values + "; path=/";
</script>
```

phpglobalread.php:

```
<?php
$messsage = $_COOKIE["textout"];
if($message != "") { echo $message; }
else { echo "Fail to read."; }
?>
```

output of phpglobalread.html:

```
Fail to read.
```

I tried reading the cookie in javascript and it works, but I can't read in php. Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
$messsage = $_COOKIE["textout"];
if($message != "") { echo $message; }
else { echo "Fail to read."; }
?>
```

You're saying $messsage = $_COOKIE["textout"]; , but on your IF your var is $message not $messsage.

Try:

```
<?php
$message = $_COOKIE["textout"];
if($message != "") { echo $message; }
else { echo "Fail to read."; }
?>
```